# Determine if value in one column comes before value in another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a new column `EDbeforesurgery` if instances where `ED`=1 comes before `surgery`=1 within a group based on the variable `order`.

Here is a snippet of my dataframe:

```
 df <- data.frame(
  group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  order = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  ED = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  surgery = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

So the ideal output for `group` 1, 2, 3 would be `Y`, `N`, `N`, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(EDbeforesurgery = any(cummax(ED) > cummax(surgery)) && any(surgery == 1L), .by = group)

  group order ED surgery EDbeforesurgery
1     1     1  1       0            TRUE
2     1     2  0       0            TRUE
3     1     3  0       1            TRUE
4     2     1  1       0           FALSE
5     2     2  1       0           FALSE
6     3     1  0       0           FALSE
7     3     2  0       1           FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `dplyr` option:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(EDbeforesurgery = isTRUE(first(order[ED == 1]) < first(order[surgery == 1]))) %>%
  ungroup()

#   group order ED surgery EDbeforesurgery
# 1     1     1  1       0            TRUE
# 2     1     2  0       0            TRUE
# 3     1     3  0       1            TRUE
# 4     2     1  1       0           FALSE
# 5     2     2  1       0           FALSE
# 6     3     1  0       0           FALSE
# 7     3     2  0       1           FALSE
```

Comment: Nice, works with `summarise(....)` to give OP's desired output.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work if there is a group that looks like this: 
`df <- data.frame(
  group = c(1, 1, 1),
  order = c(1, 2, 3),
  ED = c(1, 0, 1),
  surgery = c(0, 1, 0))`
Ideally, I would also like this example to be TRUE

Comment: @ltong oh I fixed it! I mistake the order of `first()` and `last()`.

Comment: This fails if both ED and surgery are 1.